# How to slice a python pandas dataframe with 1200 rows into 12 equal parts?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, python-2.x

How to slice a python pandas data-frame with 1200 rows into 12 equal parts? either in Python2 or Python 3

Comment: use `np.array_split(df, 100)`

Comment: change 100 to 12, try this `np.array_split(df, 12)`

Comment: Love this comment thread :)

Comment: Love this comment thread :)  too

Answer (score 2):

You can do it several ways.  I'd use `groupby` and a dictionary comprehension.  Even then, there are two obvious and distinct ways to split it.

Consider the dataframe `df`

```
df = pd.DataFrame(dict(A=np.arange(1200)))
```

***contiguous***
Meaning, grab the first 100, then the next, so on and so forth

```
twelve_equal_dfs_contiguous = \
    {name: group for name, group in df.groupby(np.arange(1200) // 100)}
```

***stratified***
Meaning, grab every other 100 starting with the first.  Then repeat starting with the second, so on and so forth

```
twelve_equal_dfs_stratified = \
    {name: group for name, group in df.groupby(np.arange(1200) % 100)}
```

---

There are too many ways to do this.  Hopefully this is some guidance on where to start.